# Close database connections automatically with Jersey CDI?

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-2.0

I would like to inject an object which implements AutoClosable to a jersey resource and have it automatically closed by the framework at the end of the request.
Basically this is a database connection provider and open connections should be closed at the end of the request.
When using the `@inject` annotation the object is not closed.
Is this possible, and how?

Comment: Are you using Jersey 2.x?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`CloseableService`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.19/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/CloseableService.html)

> The service may be used within the scope of a request to add instances of `Closeable` that are to be closed when the request goes out of scope, more specifically after the request has been processed and the response has been returned.

You can inject this service into a `Factory` where you can create your your provider. Just add the provider to the `CloseableService` inside the `Factory`, and it will be closed at the end of the request.

```
public class ConnectionProviderFactory implements Factory<ConnectionProvider> {

    @Inject
    private CloseableService closeableService;

    @Override
    public ConnectionProvider provider() {
        ConnectionProvider provider = new ConnectionProvider();
        closeableService.add(provider);
        return provider;
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose(ConnectionProvider provider) {
    }
}
```

Then just register the factory in your binder

```
bindFactory(ConnectionProviderFactory.class)
        .to(ConnectionProvider.class)
        .in(RequestScoped.class);
```

Note that the `Factory` class has a `dispose` method. I am not 100 percent sure on the details of how it works, as I have had experiences where sometimes it *is* called, and sometimes it isn't. I've found the `CloseableService` to be more reliable. Maybe one of these days I'll go digging around to try and solve the mystery of the `dispose` method for myself.

---

UPDATE

Not quite sure what you're doing differently, but below is a complete test using Jersey Test Framework. Run it like any other JUnit test. Only difference is instead of `AutoCloseable`, I use `Closeable`

```
import java.io.Closeable;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import org.glassfish.hk2.api.Factory;
import org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder;
import org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter;
import org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScoped;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.CloseableService;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.junit.Test;

public class InjectCloseableTest extends JerseyTest {
    
    public static final String CONNECTION_MSG = "Connection";
    
    public static class ConnectionProvider implements Closeable {
        private static final Logger LOGGER
                = Logger.getLogger(ConnectionProvider.class.getName());
        
        public String getConnection() {
            return CONNECTION_MSG;
        }

        @Override
        public void close() {
            LOGGER.info("---- Closing Connection ----");
        }  
    }
    
    @Path("connection")
    public static class ConnectionResource {
        
        @Inject
        ConnectionProvider connectionProvider;
        
        @GET
        public String get() {
            return connectionProvider.getConnection();
        }
    }
    
    public static class ConnectionProviderFactory implements Factory<ConnectionProvider> {
        
        @Inject
        CloseableService closeableService;

        @Override
        public ConnectionProvider provide() {
            ConnectionProvider provider = new ConnectionProvider();
            closeableService.add(provider);
            return provider;
        }

        @Override
        public void dispose(ConnectionProvider t) {} 
    }
    
    @Override
    public ResourceConfig configure() {
        return new ResourceConfig(ConnectionResource.class)
                .register(new LoggingFilter(Logger.getAnonymousLogger(), true))
                .register(new AbstractBinder() {
                    @Override
                    protected void configure() {
                        bindFactory(ConnectionProviderFactory.class)
                                .to(ConnectionProvider.class)
                                .in(RequestScoped.class);
                    }
                });
    }
    
    @Test
    public void doit() {
        Response response = target("connection").request().get();
        assertEquals(200, response.getStatus());
        assertEquals(CONNECTION_MSG, response.readEntity(String.class));
        response.close();
    }
}
```

This is the only dependency you need to run it.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-grizzly2</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Can't seem to get it to work. tried a bunch of combinations. I'm getting: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid injectee with required type of null passed to getInjecteeDescriptor

Comment: Got it to work. I was using `@Context` annotation instead of `@Inject`. Also in my case I had to register: bind(ConnectionProviderFactory.class).to(ConnectionProviderFactory.class);

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the [`@Disposes`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/inject/Disposes.html) annotation.

The [`@Disposes`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/inject/Disposes.html) annotation identifies the disposed parameter of a [disposer method](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/cdi-adv003.htm#sthref1422), allowing the application to perform customized cleanup of an object returned by a [producer method](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/cdi-adv003.htm#sthref1420) or [producer field](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/cdi-adv003.htm#sthref1421). The disposer method is called automatically when the scope ends.

---

I don't know how your database connection provider looks like, but this example will give you the general idea on how to use the [`@Disposes`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/inject/Disposes.html) annotation:

```java
public class Resources {

    @Produces
    @UserDatabase
    @RequestScoped
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public void close(@Disposes @UserDatabase EntityManager em) {
        em.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's interesting but this doesn't really feel like IOC. The point is that the class should not be responsible for importing and disposing of resources. It should be handled by the framework.

Comment: @GaryH Could you clarify your comment?

Comment: I was just speaking generally about IOC = inversion of control and dependency injection design patterns. The goal of the patterns is to "factor out" the logic needed to create or destroy resources used by the class. In your answer however this is handled by the class itself.

Comment: @GaryH I understand your point. However, as far as I know, disposing CDI beans is not related to implementing [`AutoCloseable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) or [`Closeable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html).

Comment: Maybe I'm not sure. DI framework have the concept of "Scope" like request scope. It seems only logical that if an AutoClosable is created in "scope" it should be closed when the scope is closed. It is part of the scope.

Comment: @GaryH The CDI specification is evolving. Maybe, it can be covered in a future version of the specification.